# Stop a chain of methods without returning booleans

Tags: java, boolean

I have not doubt that there is a solution posted for this, but I can't find the search term retrieve it, so if it does exist please point me to the duplicate and mark this as such.

I have a chain of methods performing various validation checks on a button click event, I display a message if the validation has failed, currently my solution is to then pass back a boolean so that if the method failed the remaining methods will not run.

I don't like this, when I have several methods all passing back booleans my code starts to smell.

is there a better solution to this? (I'd don't want to use a instance variable)

Example of the code as it currently stands:

```
private void SUBMIT_BUTTON_CLICK(){

        if(validate()){

        //Do Stuff

    }
}

private boolean validate(){

    return checkOne() && checkTow() && checkThree() && checkFour();

}

private boolean checkOne(){

    if (someCheckFails) {

        print(warning);
        return false;

    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

private boolean checkTow(){

    if (someCheckFails) {

        print(warning);
        return false;

    } else {
        return true;
    }

}

private boolean checkThree(){

    if (someCheckFails) {

        print(warning);
        return false;

    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

private boolean checkFour(){

    if (someCheckFails) {

        print(warning);
        return false;

    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like you want to use exceptions, e.g. something like this `try { validate(); performTheNormalOperation(); } catch( WhateverExceptionYouExpect e) { handleException(); }`.

Comment: @Thomas You should write that as an answer.

Comment: You can save some repetition by reusing `boolean printIfFalse(Sting s, boolean b) { if(!b) { print(s); } return b)`. Then your checks all contain `return printIfFalse("warning", sometest());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chaining like you are currently doing is generally the best solution.  It is easy to understand, efficient and (relatively) concise.

A couple of other ideas would be:

- build an array of predicates and then iterate and call them, or
- use exceptions and exception handling

but both of these have performance implications, and they will only give "cleaner" code if you have a vast number of predicates to evaluate.

Sometimes an inelegant solution is more elegant than looking for a clever solution.

---

Consider this: if I use exceptions, I can rewrite the `validate()` method

```
private boolean validate(){
    return checkOne() && checkTow() && checkThree() && checkFour();
}
```

as

```
private void validate() throws ValidationException {
    checkOne(); checkTow(); checkThree(); checkFour();
}
```

But how much have I actually gained here?  It is still two lines of code.  And if I were to follow Java's style rules it would be:

```
private void validate() throws ValidationException {
    checkOne(); 
    checkTow(); 
    checkThree(); 
    checkFour();
}
```

which is *more* lines than we started with.  And we haven't considered the predicates themselves or the code that handles the validation exception.

Comment: Yeah, from the answers I've received here it looks like my current inelegant solution is sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

Convenionally you would use exceptions:

```
void check1(Foo value) {
    if(some test on value) {
        throw new ValidationException(...);
    }
}


try {
    check1(value);
    check2(value);
} catch (ValidationException e) {
    // deal with validation failure
}
```

A bonus here is that the exception can carry information about the failure. Your boolean `false` just says "it failed", with no explanation.

Another bonus, of course, is that you're free to pass the exception higher up the call stack, where some other code can deal with it.

Some people worry about the cost of building exceptions (or more accurately, collecting that stack trace contained within). I'd advise not worrying about it unless you get performance problems and profiling points the finger at exceptions.

---

There are alternatives though. For example your validation could return `Optional<ValidationError>`:

```
Optional<ValidationError> check1(Foo value) {
   if(some test on value) {
       return Optional.of(new ValidationError(...));
   } else {
       return Optional.empty();
   }
}
```

Then...

```
Optional<ValidationError> validationResult = 
     check1(value)
     .orElseGet( () -> check2(value))
     .orElseGet( () -> check3(value));
```

You could, of course, loop through a list of validators, rather than hard-code like this.

Some of the functional programming libraries (e.g. vavr) include an `Either` class, which can be used in a similar way, where instead of being either an error or `empty()`, it's an error or a success value.

---

Or you could stick with methods returning boolean, but use them as `Predicate`s:

```
 List<Predicate<Foo>> checks = Arrays.asList(
      f -> check1(f),
      f -> check2(f),
      f -> check3(f)
 );
```

(Or the equivalent with method references e.g. `this::check1`)

```
checks.stream().allMatch(check -> check.test(value));
```

---

As you can see, there are tons of possibilities. But think about whether you're over-complicating. There's mostly nothing inherently wrong with the simple approach you already have -- although it *is* better, and more testable, to return a failure reason, rather than print it as a side-effect.

Comment: Some good alternatives, but as you've pointed out I think I would be over-complicating it using any of these over the current implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my comment: you're probably after exceptions.

Example (pseudo code):

```
void checkOne() {
  if( check_fails ) {
    throw new CheckOneException();
  }
}

void checkTwo() {
  if( check_fails ) {
    throw new CheckTwoException();
  }
}

void validate() {
  checkOne();
  checkTwo();
}

void SUBMIT_BUTTON_CLICK() {
  try {
    validate();

    //Do Stuff
  } catch( CheckOneException | CheckTwoException ) {
    //handle the exceptions
  }
}
```

Note that you might have to either declare the exceptions to be thrown or make them runtime exceptions.

Additionally you might want to use multiple catch-blocks if the handling depends on the type of exception. Alternatively you could also throw the same type of exception if that fits your needs.

Comment: I like this solution, but ultimately it's not that much cleaner than what I'm already doing.

Comment: @Johntk yes it's not that much cleaner. However, it depends on your needs: reducing the lines of code is not always a good thing and if that's your only goal you can stick with your way as well. If performance isn't too much of an issue you could also try some rule based approach, i.e. use a system that you can feed the validation rules and the data to be validated to (you need those anyways) and let it to the rest. The advantage of exceptions over your approach would be the possibility to pass information where and why validation failed.